# Remove string between two space characters with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed, bioinformatics, fasta

somehow I can't wrap my head around this. I have the following string:

`>sp.A9L976 PSBA_LEMMI Photosystem II protein D1 organism=Lemna minor taxid=4472 gene=psbA`

I would like to use sed to remove the string between the 1th and 2nd occurrence of a space. Hence, in this case, the `PSBA_LEMMI` should be removed. The string between the first two spaces does not contain any special characters.

So far I tried the following:

```
sed 's/\s.*\s/\s/'
```

But this removes everything unitl the last occurring space string, resulting in:`>sp.A9L976 TESTgene=psbA`. I thought by leaving out the greedy expression `g` sed will only match the first occurrence of the string. I also tried:

```
sed 's/(?<=\s).*(?=\s)//'
```

But this did not match / remove anything. Can someone help me out here? What am I missing?

Comment: Using awk this is just `awk '{$2 = ""} 1' file`

Comment: That is very elegant! Thx a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -E 's/\s+\S+\s+/ /'
sed -E 's/[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/ /'
```

The two POSIX ERE patterns are the same, they match one or more whitespaces, one or more non-whitespaces, and one or more whitespaces, just `\s` and `\S` pattern can only be used in the GNU `sed` version.

Note that you cannot use `\s` as a whitespace char in the replacement part. `\s` is a regex pattern, and regex is used in the LHS (left-hand side) to *search for* whitespaces. So, a literal space is required to replace *with* a space.

Since you can also use an `awk` solution you may  use

```sh
awk '{$2=""}1' file
```

Here, the lines ("records") are split into "fields" with whitespace (it is the default field separator), and the second field (`$2`) value is cleared with `{$2 = ""}` and the `1` forces awk to output the result (calling the default `print` command).

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you very much. I accepted your answer as it solved my problem via sed and provided me with useful insights.

Answer (score 2):

To edit the header of the fasta file as you specify, use this Perl one-liner:

```
echo '>sp.A9L976 PSBA_LEMMI Photosystem II protein D1 organism=Lemna minor taxid=4472 gene=psbA' | perl -lpe 's{^(>\S+\s+)\S+\s+}{$1}'
```

Prints:

```
>sp.A9L976 Photosystem II protein D1 organism=Lemna minor taxid=4472 gene=psbA
```

Note that it changes the **fasta headers only**, keeping the sequence intact even in the relatively rare cases when the sequence has whitespace. This is important in bioinformatics applications:

```
echo ">sp.A9L976 PSBA_LEMMI Photosystem II protein D1 organism=Lemna minor taxid=4472 gene=psbA\nACTG ACTG ACTG" | perl -pe 's{^(>\S+\s+)\S+\s+}{$1}'
```

Prints:

```
>sp.A9L976 Photosystem II protein D1 organism=Lemna minor taxid=4472 gene=psbA
ACTG ACTG ACTG
```

To edit the file in place:

```
perl -i.bak -lpe 's{^(>\S+\s+)\S+\s+}{$1}' in_file.fasta
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`.

Here,
`^` : beginning of the line.
`>` : literal "greater than" character, which marks the beginning of the header in fasta format specifications.
`\S+` : 1 or more non-whitespace characters.
`\s+` : 1 or more whitespace characters.
`$1` : 1st captured pattern. Capture occurs using parentheses: `(...)`.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: In such scenarios, the `(.*)` in the regex and `$2` in the replacement pattern can be both removed. We needn't touch the text after the second "word".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for the suggestion to remove the unnecessary `(.*)` and `$2`. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `sed`

```
sed 's/\(\.[^\s]*\) .[^\s]* \(.*\)/\1 \2/' input_file
```

This utilizes grouping to exclude the match between the first and second occurance of a space.

**Output**

```
>sp.A9L976 Photosystem II protein D1 organism=Lemna minor taxid=4472 gene=psbA
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your help!